# How to properly expose/publish ports for a WebUI-based application in Docker?

Tags: docker, networking, web-applications

I'm trying to port [this](https://github.com/itkach/aard2-web) webapp to Docker. I wrote the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
MAINTAINER <name>
COPY aard2-web-0.7-java6.jar /home/aard2-web-0.7-java6.jar
COPY start.sh /home/start.sh
CMD ["bash", "/home/start.sh"]
EXPOSE 8013/tcp
```

Here are the contents of `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Dslobber.browse=true -jar /home/aard2-web-0.7-java6.jar /home/dicts/*.slob
```

Then I built the image:

`docker build -t aard2-docker .`

And I used the following command to run the container:

`docker run --name Aard2 -p 127.0.0.1:8013:8013 -v /home/<name>/dicts:/home/dicts aard2-docker`

The app is running normally, prompting that it's listening at http://127.0.0.1:8013. However, I opened the address only to find that I couldn't connect to the app.
I tried using the `EXPOSE` command (as shown in the Dockerfile snippet above) and variants of the `-p` flag, such as `-p 127.0.0.1:8013:8013`, `-p 8013:8013`, `-p 8013:8013/tcp`, but none of them worked.

How can I expose/publish the port to 127.0.0.1 properly? Thanks!

Comment: using `-p 8013:8013` within the docker run command should be OK. Have you tried using `http://localhost:8013` instead of `127.0.0.1`?. I have no idea how the server works, but you may want it to be listening in `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`. When dealing with docker containers, ips can be little tricky.

Comment: Run run command of your container is a bash script called start.sh. Are you sure that start.sh is listening on port 8013 in the Container? Because mapping 8013 in the Container to 8013 on the Host only forwards requests from the host on port 8013 to the container on port 8013. There should be something listening on 8013 in the container.

Comment: @usuario I tried http://localhost:8013 but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the response from the original author:

> you need to tell the server to listen on all network interfaces instead of localhost - that is you are missing -Dslobber.host=0.0.0.0
>
> this works for me:
>
> ```
> FROM anapsix/alpine-java
> COPY ./build/libs/aard2-web-0.7.jar /home/aard2-web-0.7.jar
> CMD ["bash", "-c", "java -Dslobber.host=0.0.0.0 -jar /home/aard2-web-0.7.jar /dicts/*.slob"]
> EXPOSE 8013/tcp
> ```
>
> and then run like this:
>
> `docker run -v $HOME/Downloads:/dicts -p 8013:8013 --rm aard2-web`
>
> `-Dslobber.browse=true` opens default browser, I don't think this has any effect in docker so don't need that.
>
> https://github.com/itkach/aard2-web/issues/12#issuecomment-895557949